# Lipo Battery Voltage Drop When Pi 3B and LCD Screen Are Both Connected to Powerboost 1000

Tags: pi-3, voltage

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B and LCD Controller Board connected to a Powerboost 1000 Basic. A Lipo Battery Charger is connected to the Powerboost as well.

I noticed if I remove the LCD Controller board from the Powerboost, the battery voltage reads 4.05v when powering on the Pi. When both LCD Controller Board and Pi are connected, the battery voltage drops to 3.85-3.9v when powering on.

Is there any way or workaround to keep that initial 4.05v when both Pi and LCD Board are connected?

Answer (score 0):

Increased current consumption = decreased battery voltage.

If the capacity of the battery is low, the voltage drop will be bigger.

The only solution is to increase the battery capacity.

It could also be a indication that the power supply or the USB cable is inadequate for the increased power consumption.

Comment: Correct, that reading of 3.85-3.9v was on a 2500mah lipo. I used a 4400mah and it read 3.97v when powering the Pi and LCD Board. 

I'm guessing a 6000+mah Lipo would be the only way to get 4.05v when powering both components.

Comment: I am not agreeing with you on that, you will have voltage drop in anyway and they are because of increased power consumption, its Ohm's law.

Comment: Ohm's law is just a part of this.  The real issue is that the battery has a max current output and you are likely exceeding it.  A higher capacity battery at the same voltage actually has more cells, and since the additional cells are in parallel, it should be able to put out more current.

Comment: The OP has: "Battery" - "Powerboost 1000 Basic" - Power consumers (Raspberry Pi and LCD Board", so the weakest link is either the "Powerboost 1000 Basic" or the cables between the "Powerboost 1000 Basic" and the consumers. And the OP have tried several batteries, see comments. Ref.: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2030

Comment: Good point.  High resistance USB cables can cause a voltage drop.  Look for usb cables with a full 2.4+ amp rating which are typically thicker than other cables.  I have had to buy new usb cables to power my pis, and that has dramatically reduced crashes likely caused by voltage brown outs.

Answer (score 0):

What your seeing is what I would expect. Your batteries have an internal resistance (think of it as in series with its output). This internal resistance typically increases in value as the battery ages. Your wire also has a resistance. So add those two resistances together and you have your source resistance. Using Ohm's law you can quite easily calculate the expected voltage drop if you know the current and load. If you know the current the resistance can be calculated from the voltage drop. There are many Ohm's law calculators available online, same for wire size calculators.

Powerboost 1000 Basic is rated at 1000mA, that is light for the Raspberry without even considering what the LCD and other possible loades require. I seriously would consider something that has a capacity of several amps with a regulated output. The Raspberry pie does not have an onboard regulator. The LCD board is drawing power, that is why when it is removed the battery voltage increases.